# Allowing any string except the one containing specific format of numbers using regular expression

Tags: regex

**My Requirement:**

I have to allow any string input in a textBox but it should not contain a 10 digit number in either of following formats:

```
dddddddddd
```

OR

```
dddddd-dddd
```

The regular expression which I have used is I have used is

```
^((?!\d{10})(?!\d{6}-\d{4}).)*$
```

It works fine but does not allow an input of more than 10 digits also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `((?!\d{10})(?!\d{6}-\d{4}).)*` is a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) that matches any char, 0 or more times, that does not start a 10-digit or 6-digit+`-`+4-digit char sequences. It "disallows" a string to *contain* these patterns.

You can use

```
^(?!\d{6}-?\d{4}$).*$
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nSKaRu/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!\d{6}-?\d{4}$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the whole string is either 10 digits, with an optional `-` between the 6th and the 7th digit
- `.*$` - the rest of the string.

NOTE: you do not need `$` at the end, actually, but you may keep it for additional clarity. `.*` matches to the end of the line by default, and if there can be no line breaks, the `$` is totally redundant.